# How to make constraint objects without VisualFormat in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nslayoutconstraint

I am manually adding a bunch of layout constraints that are for portrait mode. Now I want to make two sets of constraints, and flip between them based on whether the device is in landscape or portrait mode. I do not want to use "visualformatting".

My existing/working constraint looks like this:

```
mainview.addConstraint( NSLayoutConstraint(item: vPic, attribute: .Top,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainview, attribute: .Top,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0) )
```

But I want to put the constraint in to an array (along with others), and apply them when the device rotates:

```
var constraintsPortrait = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

constraintsPortrait.extend(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vPic, attribute: .Top,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainview, attribute: .Top,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

mainview.addConstraints(constraintsPortrait)
```

I get an error on the 2nd line:

```
Type 'NSLayoutConstraint' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'
```

The only examples I can find on the web, are for how to create the constraint as an object, using the "visualformat" syntax. Like this:

```
let view2_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[view2(>=40)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's because `extend` is not `append`. They rhyme but they are not the same. Your question has _nothing_ to do with how to make NSLayoutConstraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`extend` is to concat `Array`(or arbitrary `SequenceType`) to `Array`. You should use `append` instead.

```
var constraintsPortrait = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
constraintsPortrait.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vPic, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainview, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
mainview.addConstraints(constraintsPortrait)
```

But in your case, you don't have to prepare an array for this. You can directly add a constraint with `addConstraint` method.

```
mainview.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vPic, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainview, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints in code is painful. There are third-party libraries out there that makes the process less painful. Here are some of them.

[Snappy](https://github.com/Masonry/Snappy)
[cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography)
[purelayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout)